# Error in deploying node app in service fabric ubuntu

Tags: node.js, deployment, ubuntu-16.04, azure-service-fabric

Hello I am trying to deploy a Node+Mongo application in Azure service fabric cluster but getting error after installation complete.

I have just package the node application using `yo azuresfguest` command as given in documentation.

After that I have followed this step :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux

So after installation is complete I am getting following error:-

`Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testcluster.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com', port=19080): Max retries exceeded with url: /ApplicationTypes/$/Provision?api-version=6.2&timeout=60 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 504 error responses',))`

**Any changes should I make here ?**

Comment: The url /ApplicationTypes/$/Provision?api-version=6.2&timeout=60 does not look like a url would.

Comment: @matcheek I didn't get you. I have a cluster running on same url `https://testcluster.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer/index.html#/`